# Guaranteed copy elision and forward declaration of returned type

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, copy-elision

I want to write a common interface using CRTP, for all types that define some group of functions.
The following code does not compile, because I call a function before the definition of its returned type:

```
// interface.h

struct Obj;

template <typename Derived>
struct Interface
{
    // error: return type 'struct Obj' is incomplete
    Obj f() const { return static_cast<const Derived&>(*this).f_impl(); }
};

// a.h

struct A : Interface<A>
{
    Obj f_impl();
};

// obj.h

struct Obj{};

// a.cpp

#include "a.h"
#include "obj.h"

Obj A::f_impl()
{
    return {};
}
```

With C++17 and guaranteed copy elision, I expected the compiler to no longer need the definition of Obj when defining f. Is this possible? Or is it mandatory to #include obj.h in interface.h? The second option is annoying since it considerably increases the compilation time.

Comment: Isn't this solved by using `auto` instead of `Obj` as return type?

Comment: Yes :) I tried `auto` with Visual 2017 and it did not work. I forgot to try this with Compiler Explorer before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even with "guaranteed copy elision" (which, unfortunately, is a bit of a misnomer), the C++ standard requires [[dcl.fct]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#11) that the return type of a function

> […] shall not be an incomplete (possibly cv-qualified) class type in the context of the function definition unless the function is deleted.

Using a placeholder type for the return type in your function definition (as was also suggested by Max Langhof in the comments) should work around the problem in this case:

```cpp
template <typename Derived>
struct Interface
{
    auto f() const { return static_cast<const Derived&>(*this).f_impl(); }
};
```

working example [here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:22,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:22,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:22,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:22),source:'%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+Derived%3E%0Astruct+Interface%0A%7B%0A++++auto+f()+const+%7B+return+static_cast%3Cconst+Derived%26%3E(*this).f_impl()%3B+%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+Obj%3B%0A%0Astruct+A+:+Interface%3CA%3E%0A%7B%0A++++Obj+f_impl()%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+Obj%7B%7D%3B%0A%0AObj+A::f_impl()%0A%7B%0A++++return+%7B%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Note that "guaranteed copy elision" really is not a guarantee that a copy will be elided as much as it is a change to the language that means that a copy is never made in the first place. Without there being a copy, there is also nothing to elide…

Not making a copy means the compiler has to construct an object directly in the destination of the return value instead. And doing so requires a complete type…